# How do I query DocuSign envelopes ignoring results in Deleted Items?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to make sure my application doesn't create a second envelope for someone who already has one that's **created** or **sent**. I check the existence of my database for these envelopes first, and if they don't exist there I also double-check with DocuSign via API before creating a new envelope.

So, I query for envelopes that match a particular custom_field in my app...

**GET** `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{account_id}}/envelopes/?from_date=2023-01-01&status=created,sent&custom_field=registration_id%3D123456`

The problem with this query is that it's returning everything it matches, even if some of them are in the Deleted Items folder. I can see that by appending `&include=folders` to my request.

Is it possible to ignore **Deleted Items** in my query?

Answer (score 1):

Specific the `folder_ids` (comma separated) that you wish

as en example:

For more details - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/

```
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{account_id}}/envelopes/?from_date=2023-01-01&status=created,sent&custom_field=registration_id%3D123456&folder_ids=completed,draft
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, if I append &folder_ids=completed,draft to the endpoint in my original question, I get the error "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER: The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'custom_field' cannot be specified with a pre-defined search folder, that is: 'awaiting_my_signature', 'drafts', 'expiring_soon' or 'out_for_signature'." Unfortunately I'm not sure how I can work around this limitation other than querying by my custom_field with folders included and then filtering the results locally.

Comment: Yes, I think you may have to do that, the combination of filters you're using is not allowed